# How to sum numbers from input?

Tags: python-3.x, input, integer, sum

I am working on the following problem.

Write a program that continually prompts for positive integers and stops when the sum of numbers entered exceeds 1000. 
But my code stop early if a negative integer is entered.

The numbers will not sum.

My code:

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
total = 0
sum = 0
while (0 <= x):
    if sum <= 1000:
        x += 1
        sum += (int(input("Enter an integer:")))
    elif sum >= 1000:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 0
total = 0
sum = 0
while sum <= 1000:
    x = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
    if x<0:
        print("Invalid negative value given")
        break
    sum += x
```

**First:**

```
if sum >= 1000:
    ...
elif sum < 1000:
    ...
```

is redundant, because if you chek for `sum >= 1000`, and the `elif` is reached, you aready know, that the condition was `False` and therefore `sum < 1000` has to be true. So you could replace it with

```
if sum >= 1000:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

**Second:**
You want to use `x` to check, whether the input is negative. Until now, you were simpy increasing it by one each time. Instead, you should first assing the input to `x`, and then add this to `sum`. So do it like this:

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
if x<0:
    break
sum += x
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to stop as soon as you encounter the negative number.

```
x = 0
total = 0
sum = 0
while (sum <= 1000):
    x = (int(input("Enter an integer:"))
    if (x < 0):
        break
    else:
        sum += x
```